# Probability: Six dice are rolled. What's the probability that exactly four dice have the exact same value (from 1-6)?

Tags: probability

> Six dice are rolled. What's the probability that exactly four dice have the exact same value (from 1-6)?

I have this problem in my probability course, and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I suppose you mean *four* dice have the same value. Please correct header, and also show what effort you have made and where you are stuck. Surely you have *some* idea of how to start ?

Comment: yes , my mistake

Comment: we can take an example : 1,2,4,4,4,4  or 2,5,6,6,6,6 etc...

Comment: @AlexandruHarai Thar's a  good idea. What is the prob. To roll the numbers 1,2,4,4,4,4 ?

Comment: The idea is that we roll 6 dices and we must to calculate the probability to have a cvadruple (to appear a number 4 times so 4 dices to have the same number and the other 2 to have any other combinations of numbers like 1,2,5,5,5,5 or 2,5,6,6,6,6 etc..)

Comment: Do you intend that **exactly** four of the six dice are showing the same number, or that **at least** four of the six dice are showing the same number?

Comment: exactly four yes

Comment: "I have this problem in my probability course, and I don't know how to solve it." : In accordance with [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) there are several details that you need to add directly into your posting.  The primary one that I am interested in you showing is a description of the tools, as described by the linked article, that you have been provided with.

Comment: For what it's worth, as you examine the linked article, it may occur to you that it is impossible to show work unless you first do work.  Further, it is impossible to do work unless you first, either consciously or subconsciously gather the tools that you regard as pertinent.  This is why I regard this often ovelooked preliminary step as critical.

Comment: Have you learnt combinations and permutations ?

Comment: yes i used them

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Good.  The standard approach, for this type of problem is to compute the probability as $$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}}.$$  **For convenience**, assume that the six dice are distinguishable, and are labeled T-1,T-2,T-3,T-4,T-5,T-6.  For the above expression, the first question is, what is the computation of $D$?  For example, there are $6$ choices for T-1, $6$ choices for T-2, and so on.  To compute $N$, you have to first decide which element in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ will appear four times.  ...see next comment

Comment: Then, you have to choose which four of the six dice that will show this number.  Then, for the remaining two dice that are not showing that number, how many choices are there for each of these two remaining dice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This how I would do this problem:
The probability the first four dice come up 1 and the last two are any other number is $(1/6)(1/6)(1/6)(1/6)(5/6)(5/6)= 25/6^6$.  It is easy to see that the probability any specific 4 are 6 and the other two are not is also $25/6^6$ since that just moves the "(1/6)" and "(5/6)" around but we still have 4 "(1/6)" and 2 "(5/6)".  There are $\frac{6!}{4!2$}$ ways to order 4 of one object (the "(1/6)"s) and 2 of another (the "(5/6)"s) so the probablty of 4 "1"s and 2 of any other number in any order is $\frac{6!}{4!2!}\left(\frac{25}{6^6}\right)$.

And what is the probability of four "2"s and two of any other number?  Since the probabilities of all numbers is the same, 1/6, exactly the same, $\frac{6!}{4!2!}\left(\frac{25}{6^6}\right)$.

And that is true of 3, 4, 5, and 6 as well.

So the probability of exactly 4 out of 6 dice having the same number is $\left(\frac{6!}{4!2!}\left(\frac{25}{6^6}\right)\right)^6$.

Comment: The last line of this solution is incorrect. Your expression would give a probability on the order of $10^{-13}$, which is clearly much too low.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*

You want a *pattern* of $4-1-1$ of a kind, eg $555512$

This can be *chosen* in $\binom61\binom52$ ways for the quadruple and $2$ singles, and multiplied by $\frac{6!}{4!}$ permutations to give the *numerator* of favorable ways.

[If patterns such as $555511$, i.e. $4-2$ of a kind are also permissible, though you haven't shown any such in your examples, replace $\binom52$ by $5^2$]

Divide by the *denominator* of total ways to get the probability.